# Was ist das Gegenteil von "Mindestlohn"?

Tags: single-word-request, antonym

Ich lerne die deutsche Sprache und wollte wissen, ob es ein solches Wort in der deutschen Sprache gibt?

Comment: *Wörter* dafür gibt es sicher, einen *Begriff* dafür eher nicht, weil Gehälter i.A. nicht in irgendeiner Form nach oben begrenzt werden.

Comment: @tofo: Gehaltsobergrenzen gibt es durchaus (für bestimmte Berufsgruppen) und eine Begrenzung für andere wird mittlerweile auch diskutiert.

Comment: @user1583209 Für meins gibt's keine. Ich wäre auch mit mehr zufrieden. Du weißt schon, was "i.A." heißt?

Comment: @tofo: Ich weiß schon, was "i.A." heißt. Meine Anmerkung bezog sich aber auf: "einen Begriff dafür eher nicht".

Comment: "Was ist das Gegenteil von Lampe?"

Comment: »Was ist das Gegenteil von ›Hirsch hinterm Garten‹? – *Reformhaus!«* (CC @vectorious weil in die gleiche Richtung zielend)

Comment: @Jan: Der Witz wäre fast an mir vorbei gegangen
(Spoiler: snɐH ɯ,ɹoʌ ɥǝᴚ)

Answer (score 3):

Es gibt verschiedene Auffassungen vom Begriff 'Gegenteil' (vgl. [de:wikipedia *Gegenteil*](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gegenteil)). Da nicht klar ist, worauf Du hinauswillst, versuche ich, alle Möglichkeiten, die hier denkbar sind, abzudecken.

## Konträres Gegenteil

Da ist zum einen das sogenannte *konträre Gegenteil*:

> Das Gegenteil einer Sache oder einer Eigenschaft ist umgangssprachlich meistens eine Sache oder eine Eigenschaft, die von der erstgenannten *eine Art Spiegelung eines gedachten Mittelpunktes* darstellt. [wikipedia]

Im Fall von "Mindestlohn" gibt es nun auch gleich zwei Möglichkeiten, ein konträres Gegenteil zu erhalten:

Man kann den Bestandteil "Mindest-" in "Mindestlohn" umkehren, und kommt zu Begriffen wie **Maximallohn**, **Höchstlohn**, etc.

Fokussiert man nicht auf das "Mindest-" in "Mindestlohn", sondern auf den Bestanteil "-lohn", dann ist **Mindeststrafe** ein konträres Gegenteil von "Mindestlohn".

## Kontradiktorisches Gegenteil

Es gibt aber auch die Vorstellung, das Gegenteil sei ein *Komplement* des ursprünglichen Wortes. Das wären in diesem Fall die Art von Lohn, die kein Mindestlohn ist (sogenanntes *kontradiktorisches Gegenteil*):

Wenn man den Mindestlohn konzeptuell auffasst, als staatlichen Eingriff in die Privautonomie und Vertragsfreiheit versteht, dann könnte man **Martklohn**, also den auf einem freien Markt entstehenden Lohn als 'Gegenteil' von "Mindestlohn" auffassen. (Gebräuchlich ist das meines Wissens aber nicht.)

Wenn man den Mindestlohn konkret auffasst, also als den Lohn, den eine konkrete Person erhält, dann erhielte man einen Begriff, der **mehr als Mindestlohn** bedeutet, aber einen solchen Begriff kenne ich nicht.

Comment: +1 für die Mindesstrafe. Der letzte Absatz aber verrennt sich, m.M. nach. Für einen Kaffeepreis von 1,80 gibt es kein Gegenteil und so ist auch nicht ein Lohn, der nicht der Mindestlohn ist, das Gegenteil von Mindestlohn.

Comment: @userunknown Naja, das ist halt die Frage, was man unter Gegenteil versteht. Das ist kontextabhängig. Wenn man Mindestlohn als "den gerade so die gesetzlichen Bestimmungen erfüllenden Lohn" konzeptualisiert, dann ist "ein Lohn, der nicht (nur) gerade so die gesetzlichen Bestimmungen erfüllt" eben eine Art Gegenteil.

Comment: Nein. Nicht jeder Satz, den man syntaktisch bilden kann, ist sinnvoll. Ich kann auch fragen was das Gegenteil von Grün ist. Das Gegenteil von heiß ist nicht einfach *nicht heiß*, das ist eine einfache Verneinung. Lauwarm ist nicht heiß, aber das Gegenteil von heiß ist kalt.

Comment: @userunknown Lies dir bitte den verlinkten Wikipedia-Artikel durch.

Comment: @userunknown: Wenn es um Verbennungsgefahr wegen Hitze geht, ist die Kälte natürlich in Lauwärme inbegriffen. Ist das Glas halb leer oder voll? Das ist halt kontextabhängig. Eigentlich kann man garnicht von Gegenteil reden, da die Temperatur kein Teil ist und nicht dem Schluessel-Schloss-Prinzip entspricht.

Comment: @jonathan.scholbach: Wenn der Mindestlohn als *Mittelpunkt* betrachtet wird, wie du zitierst, dann gibt es per Definition kein Gegenteil. Wenn du das mit in die Antwort aufnimmst, wäre das mMn. vollständig. Marktlohn finde ich auch gut.

Comment: @vectorious Das verstehe ich nicht. Nicht der Mindestlohn ist ja hier der gedachte Mittelpunkt, sondern "Mindestlohn" ist ein Extremum, dessen Spiegelung am "mittleren Lohn" den "Maximallohn" ergibt. So ist das jedenfalls von mir gemeint. In WP müsste es richtiger heißen "Spiegelung an einem gedachten Mittelpunkt"

Comment: Vgl. *Tief-**Punkt***. Natürlich ist Null auch ein (lokaler) Tiefpunkt,

Answer (score 2):

Wir können hier das Wortpaar mit der lateinischen Wurzel nutzen:

*minimum* <-> *maximum* bzw.
*minimal* <-> *maximal*

Also:
*Minimallohn* <-> *Maximallohn*

Oder auf Deutsch:
*Mindestlohn* <-> *Höchstlohn*

Comment: Rein sprachlich gesehen, ist das richtig. Aber wenn man die Definition betrachtet, ist es höchst fraglich. Dann wäre das Höchstlohn immerhin der Lohn, der "maximal rechtlich zulässig" ist. Grenzen nach oben hin fände ich zwar gut, aber das Konzept wäre mir doch neu.

Comment: @Em1 Deckelung von Managergehältern? Auch rechtlich abgesichert für Unternehmer/Banken in öffentlicher Hand? Und die Grenzen müssen nicht durch Gesetzgeber bestimmt und kontrolliert werden, auch Betriebsvereinbarungen oder Tarifverträge u.ä. kommen in Frage.

Answer (score 1):

Kurze Antwort:

- sprachlich: Maximallohn, Höchstlohn
- bei klar abgegrenzten minimalen und maximalen Entgelte: Maximallohn, Höchstlohn
- rechtlich: kein Gegenteil
- im Sinne von "ausreichend": kein Gegenteil

---

Ausführliche Antwort:

Auf sprachlicher Ebene ist die Antwort einfach. Man würde vom Maximallohn oder Höchstlohn sprechen, so wie es in einer anderen Antwort bereits erwähnt wurde.

Unter Betrachtung der Definition von Mindestlohn ist dies aber inkorrekt. Der Mindestlohn ist definiert als der Lohn, der mindestens entrichtet werden muss. Rechtlich gesehen. Eine Obergrenze gibt es vom Gesetzgeber aber nicht. Insofern gibt es kein Gegenteil zum Mindestlohn.

Dann könnte natürlich auch ein Unternehmen einen Mindestlohn bestimmt haben, den sie mindestens an ihre Arbeiter auszahlen. Der müsste natürlich mindestens dem gesetzlichen Mindestlohn entsprechen.
Nun kann zu diesem Mindestlohn natürlich ein Gegenteil in der Praxis umgesetzt werden. Der maximale Lohn, den dieses Unternehmen an einen Arbeiter entrichtet, würde dann dem Begriff entsprechen, der auf sprachlicher Ebene korrekt ist: Maximallohn bzw. Höchstlohn.

Nächste Überlegung könnte sein, was denn nun ist, wenn man unter Mindestlohn den Lohn versteht, der notwendig ist, damit man überleben kann. Sprich, ausreichend Geld zur Bezahlung der Miete, des Essens und so weiter.
Ob es hier ein Gegenteil gibt, kann man stark diskutieren. Als Gegenteil könnte man den Gehalt betrachten, der nicht ausreicht, um über die Runden zu kommen. Aber auch ein Gehalt, dass einem jeglichen Luxus erlaubt, entspräche gewissermaßen dem Gegenteil. Aber strikt genommen, sind jene Extreme gegenteilig zueinander und der Mindestlohn ist nur ein fixer Wert irgendwo in der Mitte. Folglich kein Extrem und somit kein Gegenteil.
Und was wäre exakt das Gegenteil? Der in einer anderen Antwort genannte Hungerslohn? Warum nicht "gar kein Lohn"?
Und wo beginnt Luxus?

Das ganze kann man noch weiter spinnen, aber dann diskutiere ich das Thema morgen noch...

Comment: Also rein logisch betrachtet ist das Gegenteil von *Mindestlohn* - *kein Mindestlohn*

Comment: "Mindestlohn" ist aktuell in Deutschland ein eng verstandener Begriff, aber das Wort ist weder auf die Gegenwart, noch auf Deutschland begrenzt und auch nicht auf den Kontext gesetzlicher Initiativen. Der Geschäftsführer kann einen Maximallohn kalkulieren, zu dem er noch Gewinn macht und in der Diskussion ist auch schon, ob Managermaximallöhne als Faktoren des untersten, in der Firma gezahlten Lohns, festgelegt werden sollen (das 100 oder 1000fache).

Answer (score 1):

Zur Einrichtung *Mindestlohn* gibt es kein Gegenteil, aber ein Pendant/Gegenstück:

> Obergrenze bzw. Lohnobergrenze

<sub>@user1583209 hat in seinem Kommentar schon davon gesprochen.</sub>

Inwiefern sich die Einrichtung *Obergrenze* in Deutschland findet, ist unerheblich, gefragt ist nach der deutschen Sprache, nicht nach dem deutschen Staat.

Comment: So gut der Hinweis auf die Sprache ist, die a) auch in Österreich und der Schweiz gesprochen wird, b) in Vergangenheit und Zukunft benutzt wird und c) in fiktionalen Texten verwendet wird, so falsch ist die Antwort, denn "Man zahlt mir nur den Mindestlohn" findet seine Entsprechung nicht in "Man zahlt mir die Obergrenze".

Comment: @user unknown: Da _Obergrenze_ für einen Wert steht, ist _»Man zahlt mir die Obergrenze«_ gültiges Deutsch in allen drei Ländern.

Comment: Gut. Das Gegenteil von Obergrenze ist Untergrenze - stimmst Du mir zu? Also kann man auch sagen "Man zahlt mir nur Untergrenze". Hm. Die Untergrenze, bei der in freier Natur Wasser flüssig bleibt ist 0° Celsius. Richtig? Also: Das Wort "Untergrenze" transportiert nicht den Inhalt "Lohn". Spezifisch danach war aber gefragt.

Comment: @user unknown: Auch das ist kein gültiger Einwand. In meiner Antwort steht _»... bzw. Lohnobergrenze.«_

Answer (score -1):

Da "Mindestlohn" ein Extrem ist, kann man intuitiv nach dem Gegenteil suchen. Das Problem ist aber, dass ein Extrem, das das Ende einer offenen Skala definiert, normalerweise kein Gegenteil hat.

Bezüglich deiner Frage kann man im Prinzip sagen, dass das Gegenteil von "Mindestlohn" wohl "ausreichend Lohn" ist. Da das aber subjektiv ist, scheint es mir nicht passend als generelles Gegenteil.

Die beste Beschreibung wäre dann, zugegebenermaßen trivial, "mehr Lohn als Mindestlohn". Da das aber kein Wort, sondern ein Konzept ist, würde ich sagen, dass "Mindestlohn" kein sinnvolles Gegenteil besitzt.

Comment: Ich mag dein Antwort. Ich denke 'Mindestlohn' ist auch ein Konzept und genau deswegen habe ich für das Gegenteil gefragt!.

Comment: @Andreas Pardeike: Wenn Du zum Beispiel "groß-klein"  als Gegenteilworte akzeptierst, sehe ich da keinen großen Unterschied zu "Mindestlohn-Maximallohn/Gehaltsobergrenze/Höchstlohn". In beiden Fällen beschreiben die Worte gesetzlich festgelegte Grenzen für den Lohn.

Comment: *mindest* impliziert *ausreichend*, das sind keine Gegensaetze, eher superlativ und komparativ der gleichen Idee.

Comment: ich stimme @vectorious voll zu. Der Vergleich "klein" zu "mindestens" hinkt aber.

Comment: @vectorious: Wieso impliziert Mindestlohn ausreichender Lohn? Mindestlohn ist üblicherweise ein rechtlicher Term, der angibt, wie viel (oder eher: wie wenig) für eine Vollzeitstelle zu bezahlen ist. Ob das für jemanden ausreicht, ist eine ganz andere Frage.

Comment: Ich sehe den Begriff "Mindestlohn" eher als untere Grenze eines Intervalls (das Intervall aller rechtlich zulässigen Löhne). Dementsprechend wäre Maximallohn, die obere Grenze und in gewissem Sinne das "Gegenteil". Kann sein, dass das Sprachwissenschaftler anders sehen, aber umgangssprachlich habe ich keine Probleme damit diese als Gegensätze zu bezeichnen.

Comment: Für den Arbeitgeber gibt es natürlich Maximallöhne. Das sind Löhne, die ihn nicht in den Ruin treiben. Wobei sich andere Parteien mit anderen Kriterien zu Wort melden können. An die jüngste Mindestlohndebatte ist der Begriff nicht exklusiv gebunden.

Comment: @user1583209: Logisch gesehen kann man behaupten, wer mehr als das Minimum erhalte, *der erhält tatsächlich das Minimum* und darüber hinaus noch mehr. Die andere Ansichtsweise macht natürlich auch sinn. Streng genommen ist die Verneinung von Mindestlohn eben "kein Mindesteslohn", was das im Detail bedeutet ist kontextabhängig, aber nur, weil die logische Verneinung im Sprachgebrauch halt gerne missachtet wird.

Answer (score -1):

Neben Höchstlohn (danke Stephie) ist auch das Extrem unterhalb des Minimums vorstellbar: Lohn unter Existenzminimum wird z.B. Hungerlohn genannt, allerdings kann auch ein nomineller Mindestlohn tatsächlich ein Hungerlohn sein.

Comment: Wenn man unter dem Mindestlohn zahlt ist der Maßstab immer noch der Mindestlohn. Das Gegenteil der Höchstgeschwindigkeit ist nicht das Überschreiten der Höchstgeschwindigkeit.

Comment: "Hat er sich an die Höchstgeschwindigkeit gehalten?". "Nein, im *Gegenteil*!"

Comment: Und was soll das heißen? Im Unterschied zu "Nein, hat er nicht!". Dass er statt 80 nur 20 gefahren ist?

Comment: Wer 20 in der 80er-Zone fährt, hält sich wohl an die obere Geschwindigkeitsbegrenzung. Das kann ich also nicht gemeint haben.